# Jquery adds items to the drop-down list without duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to add element to my drop-down list wihtout duplicates

```
for (var i = 0; i < queues.entities.length; i++) {
      var queuesName = queues.entities[i].name;

 $("#brandFilter").append(
        $(new Option(queues.entities[i].name.substring(0, 2)))
      );
     
    }
```

Here is my list

```
 <div>
                  <b>Brand</b>
                  <select
                    class="form-control input-sm form-control-sm border-0 brandFilter"
                    id="brandFilter"
                    multiple
                    size="3"
                  >
                    <option value="-" selected>--- All ---</option>
               </select>
                 <hr />
                </div>
```

Thank You So much

Comment: Are you running this loop multiple times on the page? You'll need to clear the list every time you do that: `$("#brandFilter").html("");`

Comment: Is the issue (as above) that you're running the same code and it's adding elements again?  Or does your `queues` have duplicates?

Comment: it has duplacate becasue i am basing on other queues. and i am taking out 2 first letters. 2 first  is equal to Country Code. If e have 6 queues with code US they are going to duplicate

Comment: i wanted to do something llike if contains (varable) end loop but It didn't work. Maybe i did something wrong

Comment: In which case, it's easier to remove the duplicates first, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects) for various solutions.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to remove the duplicates entities first.

```
  const uniqueQueuesEntities = [...new Set(queues.entities)];

  for (var i = 0; i < uniqueQueuesEntities.length; i++) {
    var queuesName = uniqueQueuesEntities[i].name;

    $("#brandFilter").append(
      $(new Option(uniqueQueuesEntities[i].name.substring(0, 2)))
    );
  }
```